# Display column from a table based on a condition from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Have 2 tables contact and customer .

```
**Contact Table**                          
id(primary key)   
org_name                                   
city                                       
state                                     
email 

**Customer Table**   
id(primary key)                                 
created_under_id  
contact_id  
notes  
credit_limit
```

Need a query to display org_name,city, state and email of all the customers with credit limit more than 25000. Display the records in ascending order based on their org_name.

I tried this query but it's not working:

```
SELECT org_name,city,state,email FROM contact  
    WHERE contact.id IN (SELECT customer.id FROM customer  
                  WHERE credit_limit >25000)ORDER BY org_name ASC;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

You might replace `customer.id` with `customer.contact_id` in the subquery.

Or, Alternatively you may use a JOIN statement between those tables as :

```
SELECT c.org_name, c.city, c.state, c.email
  FROM contact c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN customer r
    ON ( c.id = r.contact_id )
 WHERE r.credit_limit > 25000
 ORDER BY c.org_name ASC;
```

i.e. `Contact.ID` and `Customer.contact_id` are common columns to construct the relation between the tables.